# Spring MVC controller throws error media unsupported for JSON request

Tags: jquery, json, spring, spring-mvc

I receive this response when I try to send JSON object to the server. I have tested all post of stackoverflow but nothing works:

Client side:

```
function submitWOZ(){
var sub = {
     "idNextexercise": parseInt($('#exList').val()), 
     "user": $('#user').val()   
    };
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    headers: { 
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
    },
    dataType : 'json',
    url: "insertNextID",
    //data: JSON.stringfy(sub),
    data: sub,
    success: function(data){
        alert('Great!');
    },
    error : function(jqXHR, status, error) {
       alert('Sorry!, there was a problem');
    },
    complete : function(jqXHR, status) {
       alert('Done!');
    }
});
```

}

server side:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/insertNextID", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {"application/xml", "application/json"})
public @ResponseBody String insertNextExercise(@RequestBody ExerciseVO messageForm, HttpServletRequest req){}
```

Context-config:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/, classpath:/META-INF/web-resources/" />
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />

<!-- Thymeleaf template resolver -->
<bean id="templateResolver"
      class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
</bean>

<!-- Thymeleaf Template Engine -->
<bean id="templateEngine"
      class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
    <property name="additionalDialects">
        <set>
            <bean class="org.thymeleaf.extras.tiles2.dialect.TilesDialect"/>
            <bean class="org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity3.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect"/>
            <bean class="org.thymeleaf.extras.conditionalcomments.dialect.ConditionalCommentsDialect"/>
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Resolves logical view names returned by Controllers to Tiles; a view name to resolve is treated as the name of a tiles definition -->
<bean id="tilesViewResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.AjaxThymeleafViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.thymeleaf.extras.tiles2.spring.web.view.FlowAjaxThymeleafTilesView"/>
    <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine"/>
</bean>

<!-- Configures the Tiles layout system using a specific thymeleaf-enabled Tiles Configurer -->
<bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.thymeleaf.extras.tiles2.spring.web.configurer.ThymeleafTilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/**/views.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jsonHttpMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="prefixJson" value="false" />
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
        </map>
    </property>

    <property name="defaultViews">
        <list>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">
                <property name="objectMapper">
                    <ref bean="JacksonObjectMapper" />
                </property>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="false" />
    <property name="favorParameter" value="true" />
    <property name="useNotAcceptableStatusCode" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="JacksonObjectMapper" class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper" />
```

Anybody can help me? because I tested everything that I found on the internet.

Comment: mvc annoation driven means you don't have to supply beans for content negiotation/message converter. I would try removing them and the consumes in request mapping.

Comment: I also had some problems with this kind of implementation. I used this example here, maybe you find it helpful: [How to build RESTful Service with Java using JAX-RS and Jersey](http://crunchify.com/how-to-build-restful-service-with-java-using-jax-rs-and-jersey/)

Comment: do you have some error message on the server or the browser console?

Comment: if you check with chrome and firebug, what is the content of the http request?  The server might not be managing correctly the JSON sent, one common is date formats. Turn on log4j/slf4j logging in debug to see further detail

Comment: I receive this response: "The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method"

Answer (score 0):

You can debug it by adding new filter to web.xml then check if the request that is reaching the server looks like you expect. If it is ok then try to override jsonHttpMessageConverter add it to your context configuration file and just check why your call is rejected. There could be many reasons and I think the only way to solve it is to track your request on the server side and find the place where it is stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem could be that the necessary JSON/XML parsers are not on the classpath, so spring MVC cannot produce the request content.

In order to return responses in JSON/XML it's necessary to have a set of jars in the classpath.

For example for JSON we usually put the Jackson parser in the classpath using these artifacts for version 2.1:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

The exact artifacts depend on the parser used and in the case of Jackson also from the version. More ancient versions used different artifact names.

Comment: I add these dependencies to my pom but the result is the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. try removing (temporarily) the entire consumes parameter from the controller, if that works...
2. reinstate the consumes parameter and try adding `contentType: "application/json"` to the $.AJAX call instead of in the headers section.

Comment: I have tested both, but nothing. Thanks